# Remove rows based on groupby of multiple columns resulting in lowest value only

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data in a pandas dataframe in Python. I would like to group the data based on the Name and Property column, and keep only the lowest value within the Date.

Before:

```
  Name  Property                         Date
0   X1      Cash  621 days 00:00:00.000000000
1   X1      Cash  256 days 00:00:00.000000000
2   X1      Cash  101 days 00:00:00.000000000
3   X1  Overflow  352 days 00:00:00.000000000
4   X1  Overflow  101 days 00:00:00.000000000
5   X1  Overflow   53 days 00:00:00.000000000
```

Repeat for X2/X3 etc.

After:

```
  Name  Property                         Date
2   X1      Cash  101 days 00:00:00.000000000
5   X1  Overflow   53 days 00:00:00.000000000
```

I am attempting to play around with the syntax but unable to get it right:

```
df1 = df1[df1.groupby(['Name', 'Property'])['Date'].min()]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you call reset intex on the groupby.min() result, you'll have your desired output:

```
df.groupby(['Name', 'Property'])['Date'].min().reset_index()
Out: 
  Name  Property     Date
0   X1      Cash 101 days
1   X1  Overflow  53 days
```

You can also use [`nsmallest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nsmallest.html):

```
df.groupby(['Name', 'Property'])['Date'].nsmallest(1)
Out: 
Name  Property   
X1    Cash      2   101 days
      Overflow  5    53 days
Name: Date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

You can reset the index and drop the original index if you want:

```
df.groupby(['Name', 'Property'])['Date'].nsmallest(1).reset_index(level=[0, 1])
Out: 
  Name  Property     Date
2   X1      Cash 101 days
5   X1  Overflow  53 days
```

If you have additional columns you want to keep, you have several options.

```
df['additional column'] = np.arange(6)

df
Out: 
  Name  Property     Date  additional column
0   X1      Cash 621 days                  0
1   X1      Cash 256 days                  1
2   X1      Cash 101 days                  2
3   X1  Overflow 352 days                  3
4   X1  Overflow 101 days                  4
5   X1  Overflow  53 days                  5
```

The first one, as @piRSquared mentioned, is to use `loc` with the indexes of the returning rows:

```
df.loc[df.groupby(['Name', 'Property'])['Date'].idxmin()]
```

A second one would be to merge the original DataFrame and the aggregated one:

```
df.merge(df.groupby(['Name', 'Property'])['Date'].min().reset_index())
```

Both yield:

```
  Name  Property     Date  additional column
0   X1      Cash 101 days                  2
1   X1  Overflow  53 days                  5
```

Based on the use case, one may outperform the other.

Comment: Thank you @ayhan! The reset index on the .min() worked perfectly. Just a couple follow up questions:
1. I have a few other columns that are removed when I do the df = df.groupby().... command, how do I keep those columns intact?
2. How can I format my code output properly next time I need to post a question?

Comment: @rinwin For the formatting, just paste the DataFrame directly to the question box and, select it and click on the code button (with `{}` icon). As for the multiple columns: Do you want the minimum of each column, or do you want the corresponding rows for the minimum of Date? For the first one, removing `['Date']` should be enough but for the second one you may need merge. I'll add an example.

Comment: df.loc[df.groupby(['Name', 'Property'])['Date'].idxmin()]

Comment: df.sort_values('Date').drop_duplicates(['Name', 'Property'])

Comment: @piRSquared Thanks! I've added the first suggestion but as I see you have other ones. :)

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help!! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try `transform` in `pandas` , also it will not remove your additional columns.

```
DF = df[df.groupby(['Property'])['Date'].transform(min) == df['Date']]



   Name Property    Date

2   X1  Cash        101 days

5   X1  Overflow    53  days
```